# A :nth-child selector conflicts with another

Tags: css

I have used `:nth-child` for a list element - `li:nthchild(2)` in a class- "one". There is another list element on the page belonging to another class(class="two)" and the css of the class "one" applies to the list element of the class "two".

Here is the CSS of first list element"

```
.one li:nth-child(2){

    position: absolute;

    width: 80% !important;

    background-color: orange;

    color: #FFF;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

    -moz-border-radius: 2px;

    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

And this is for the class two:

```
.two li:nth-child(2) {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0 !important;
display: block;
list-style: none;
border: none;
background: none;
}
```

I don't want the class "two" to inherit the css of class one. Could any one tell me how to make the `.one li:nthchild(2)` css applies only to that class and not affect others?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your CSS..

Comment: Hello Lego Stormtroopr,I have edited the question and added the code.

Comment: @boltclocks-a-unicorn Can you tell me, what else should I do to remove the "Off-topic" tag?

Comment: Looks like `ul.two` is inside a child `li` of `ul.one`. Right?

Comment: If answer from @techfoobar doesn't solve your problem, post relevant part of your HTML code: the minimal code that can reproduce your problem. Is it even valid? Did you close your lists where you intended to do it?

Comment: @FelipeAls Yes! techfoobar 's answer resolves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `ul.two` is inside a child `li` of `ul.one`.

To correct the issue, modify your CSS like:

```
.one > li:nth-child(2) {
    ...
}
```

That should do it.